# How I manage multiple ros distributions (groovy , electric , fuerte )

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use different ros disributions(groovy / fuerte / electric) for different projects.

I have these doubts

1 - Is there any problem when I install multiple distbutions
2 - How can build and manage different distro for different projects
3 - How can I make different workspaces

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58221/how-i-manage-multiple-ros-distributions-(groovy-,-electric-,-fuerte-)/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You can have different distributions installed and make them work.

It depends on the setup.bash which your .bashrc calls

In the link below, in section 1.5 Environment setup, you can find instructions on how you can have multiple distributions ans set them up for use.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

Basically whenever a new terminal pops up, .basrc file is called. So if you source the setup of electric or fuerte in .bashrc file, the corresponding distribution is used.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-14**:
Thank you .. I new to ros... what change I need to make in .bashrc file ...Is it anything need to add or remove?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-03-14**:
To open the .bashrc file, type sudo gedit  .bashrc then add the following line at the end   source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash . Remember to close the terminal and open new one so that the .bashrc file is called. This will setup the termina to fuerte distribution

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-14**:
I already have source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash... Is this cause any problem ?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-03-14**:
i am not sure, but if want to use fuerte, better thing would be to comment the groovy and add fuerte

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-14**:
ok .. Thank you